# Can i compile .net Core 3 WPF application in Linux?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.0

WPF support was added in .net Core 3.0

Can i compile wpf application on Linux or in Linux-based docker container?

Comment: Compile, probably. Test? Most likely not, unless you ensure most of the testable code stays out of the WPF app and doesn't depend on anything Windows-specific. You could test this if you have WSL enabled on a Windows machine

Comment: "WPF support was added in .net Core 3.0" for Windows only.

Comment: @dymanoid the question asks if compilation is possible. You can compile for Ubuntu on windows by using the correct runtime identifier

Comment: You can run msbuild on a Linux server in a container which is windows  - I've used CI tooling that way in the past.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I doubt you can install and use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` that is required to build WPF apps on .NET Core 3 on any other platform than Windows. If you run a Windows container, it will probably work though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't - I just tried this in WSL2. The WPF templates appear in if you type `dotnet new`  but the result of

```
dotnet new wpf
```

fails in the restore step

```
The template "WPF Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on wpftest/wpftest.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(59,5): 
error NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications.
```

This error is thrown by the SDK's targets file itself so conditional compilation won't help. The error is thrown before compilation starts.

A good idea would be to split the project in two, a "headless" library that can be compiled, reused and *tested* in any OS and a UI library that can be built on Window.

Comment: as far you know, is there any way to "conditional compile" (include) a section of code only for a certain OS? I mean to create a single project library, but expose only a partial APIs when is targeted for Linux.

Comment: The error is thrown by the SDK's targets file itself when it encounters a WPF project. You'll have to split your project in two, a "headless" project and a UI project. That's a good design anyway, making testing and reuse a lot easier

Comment: that's what I'm doing: I also think is a good practice. However, I just wondered if that's technically feasible or not. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Your error message hepled to find some interesting discussions https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/57#issuecomment-491918057

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but the UI frameworks WinForms and WPF are Windows only even when using .NET Core.

Related:

- [Make WPF cross-platform (MacOS and Linux support) #48](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/48)