# Error NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new in C#, in Visual Studio for Mac, and I need to open a project which extension is ".sln".

When I try to do it, a message is displayed:

```
error NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications.
Unable to create package spec for project.
```

I think I can manage to open some files to modify the code and make it acceptable for Mac, but I don't know where to start searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i compile .net Core 3 WPF application in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116849/can-i-compile-net-core-3-wpf-application-in-linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972270/cannot-open-solution-file-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with net6 SDK `6.0.4xx`, it will be possible to build WPF/WinForms projects on non-windows operating systems.

It requires `<EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>` to be set in the `csproj` or a `Directory.Build.props` file.

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/30076

Answer (score 2):

You are opened solution which includes Windows desktop application (for example WinForms). It is not possible yet (at least in official / standard way) to handle such projects by Visual Studio for Mac OS X. You need to run Visual Studio on Microsoft Windows system.